# relative directory paths within a mathematica package/what directory does a mathematica package see as local?

Tags: import, packages

I have a package that gets loaded in many notebooks I use, with

```
Import[pathToLibraryDirectory<> "toolkit.m"];
```

This toolkit in turn loads some Excel spreadsheets that contain reference data. I prefer to keep this data external for reasons of supportability and ease in updating as new reference data is released.

The excel files live in a directory at the same level in the file structure as the directory that contains the toolkit.

The toolkit contains therefore

```
sheetICareAbout=Import[NotebookDirectory[]<> "..\\reference tables\\excel data notebook.xls"][[2]];
```

and this works if I open the toolkit and execute this line by hand, but it doesn't work if I save the toolkit as a package and load it that way. The `NotebookDirectory` call no longer points to the right thing. I can put in an absolute path to the directory that works in some cases, but I load this toolkit from different machines and operating systems, and the absolute paths don't always look the same.

Hence my question, is there some relative path I can refer to so that the package can find the excel files?

Comment: See also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24InputFileName)

Comment: The problem is that `NotebookDirectory[]` returns the directory of the file that is calling all this stuff, not the directory where all this stuff resides in. For that you need, as Leonid indicated, `$InputFileName`.